# How do I add a vertical scroll bar to a tab page?

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, tabs

So I have a tab container which I dynamically create and add tabs to at run time like this:-

```
    private void DynamicTabCreation()
    {


        #region Code for dynamically creating a tab

        //Getting all Product Types from database into a dataSet.
        DataBaseConnection pt = new DataBaseConnection();
        pt.passSqlCmdandFillDs = "SELECT * FROM [tblProductType]";

        foreach (DataRow row in pt.dataSetWithDB.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            //Adding new tabpages to the tabControl container, the name of each tab being the product type
                                    //Key for later use                    //Name of tab
            tabContainer.TabPages.Add((row["ProductType"].ToString()), ((string)row["Description"]));


        }

        //Make the tabs bigger so that they are touchable.
        tabContainer.ItemSize = new Size(90, 50);

        //Setting default settings for each tabpage created
        foreach (TabPage tp in tabContainer.TabPages)
        {
            tp.BackColor = Color.White;
            tp.AutoScroll = true; //Not doing anything :(
        }



        #endregion
    }
```

After doing this I add buttons to the tabpages like this:-

```
            #region Code for adding buttons which represent products into each tab

        foreach (TabPage tp in tabContainer.TabPages)
        {

            DataBaseConnection pt = new DataBaseConnection();
            pt.passSqlCmdandFillDs = "SELECT * FROM [tblProduct]";


            FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            //Will make any controls added to the tab page be placed appropiately within it.
            flp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 

            foreach (DataRow row in pt.dataSetWithDB.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (tp.Text == row["ProductType"].ToString()) //If the Product Type corrosponds with the Tab Name in the tabContainer
                {   
                    //Button generated to add to the tab page (remmember buttons represent products)
                    Button b = new Button();

                    //Giving button appropiate size so it looks good and is suffient size to be touch screen compatible
                    b.Size = new Size(80, 80);

                    //Displaying the Product/Buttons details on the button.
                    b.Text = row["Description"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "£" + Convert.ToDecimal(row["Price"]);

                    //The properties of this product object store data about the 'Product' which the button represents.
                    ProductSelected product = new ProductSelected();

                    //Setting the properties of the product from the DB.
                    product.Description = row["Description"].ToString();
                    product.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Price"]);
                    product.ProductID =  (int)row["ProductID"];



                    //Changing the image of the button
                    b.BackgroundImage = tblProducts.readimageFromDB(row);
                    b.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;




                    //changes
                    product.SecondaryID = 0;



                    //This 'Product' obj, contains all the information about the product.
                    //I am tagging it to the button
                    //So the button now represents the product object
                    b.Tag = product;

                    //Upon pressing the button, the information has to be added to the list.
                    b.Click += new EventHandler(updateProductList); 


                    //The flowlayoutpanel makes sure that all the buttons are displayed in a organised layout.
                    //The flp can be thought of as a organised container
                    //This container can then be stored into another container (later on in the code, it will be stored into the tabPage(Which we are currently looping through))
                    flp.Controls.Add(b); 

                }
            }
            //Adding flp to the tabPage that we are current accesed at in the foreach loop.
            tp.Controls.Add(flp);

        }

        #endregion

    }
```

If there are too many buttons then they overflow away from the screen, so it looks like this:-

[image: The problem and what I want]

So how will I add the vertical scroll bar in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Turning on `AutoScroll` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes turning on autoscroll isn't doing anything, I am using windows form

Comment: Well, it should. Are you sure you turned it on for the TabPage?? (Or whatever container the Buttons sit in?) - Ah, I see that you are actually adding to FLP, right? So it should be turned on for it, of course.. Or set its AutoSize to true and let the TabPage AutsoScroll. The difference is whethwer you want to keep a fixed area above the FLP from scrolling..

Comment: Thanks fixed it by putting the autoscroll property of the flp to true too.